# How to store nav menu urls in database?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I'm working on my first django app, and i have side nav menu like in twitter. To prevent the dozens of lines in my template like this

```
<ul class="nav d-flex flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item align-self-start rounded-pill mb-3"><li>
    <li class="nav-item align-self-start rounded-pill mb-3"><li>
    ...
    <li class="nav-item align-self-start rounded-pill mb-3"><li>
</ul>
```

and for app extensibility i want to store nav menu in database to be able to loop over the menu items

```
<ul class="nav d-flex flex-column">
    {% for item in menu %}
        <li class="nav-item align-self-start rounded-pill mb-3"><li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But the problem is that i can't store direct urls for menu items in database, because several of them have dynamic urls e.g. profile page, which has 'slug:username/' pattern.
I've tried to store template tags in database like

```
{% url 'app_name:view_name' %}
```

but of course it doesn't work.
My current idea is to store in database namespaced url e.g. 'app_name:view_name' for static urls and 'request.user.get_absolute_url()' for pages which have username in urls.
The next step is to get QuerySet with menu items from database, loop over them and transform namespaces url with reverse (it works), but 'request.user.get_absolute_url()' is just a string and it doesn't work. Then make list of ditcs and pass it to context

```
menu = [{item1 attrs}, {item2 attrs},...,]
```

Is exists a better approach to solve my problem? And finally what i should do with dynamic urls?

UPD:
If we're dealing with menu items whose urls depend only on usernames i.e. only on User model, we can do smth like this (NavigationMenu - table model, url_link - column with following values: 'app_name:view_name' or 'get_absolute_url'):

```
menu = NavigationMenu.object.all()
for item in menu:
    url_link = item.url_link
    if ':' in item.url_link:
        url = reverse(url_link)
    else:
        method = getattr(request.user, url_link)
        url = method()
    # then store all instance attrs in dict
```

But it seems that is not a good way to solve this.

Comment: There are some packages like https://github.com/idlesign/django-sitetree that do this almost as you describe. It has some other goodies like breadcrumbs and permissions. Might be worth a look either to use or for some inspiration. The getting started shows how to do your specific links for a particular user or category: https://django-sitetree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html. The really nice thing about this one is the permissions so only those in particular groups can see certain menu options.

Answer (score -1):

The ideal approach to achieve this is to create a base.html in which you build this sidebar nav item, and then include that base.html on every page where you want that sidebar.

This is an example of base.html

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>My Project</title>
        </head>

        <body>
        <header>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        </ul>
        </header>
        {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
        </body>
    </html>
```

Include base.html in other Html files

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Content for My App</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and  typesetting industry..</p>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: I already use this approach, but the question is different

Comment: I don't then how you will store dynamic URLs in the model.